# How to set column ticked from other column

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How can I set a value into gridview column? The thing is the column was added manually, not from the database. What I want is when the checklist value was `1` the `cek22` column got `ticked` and when value was `0` the `cek22` column was `unticked`. I used devexpress.

Example of my code that I used:

```
public void abc()
{
    //select query in here
    gridControl1.DataSource = dt;

    //iam adding a column here
    dt.Columns.Add("cek22",typeof(bool));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column is added manually then your column is working in unbound mode. So, you can just use its [unbound expression](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_UnboundExpressiontopic). If you want to update your `checklist` column from `cel22` then you can use `CellValueChanging` event.
Here is example:

```
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.AddRange(new[]
{
    new DataColumn("preferred", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("checklist", typeof(int))
});

table.Rows.Add("Director Fury", 1);
table.Rows.Add("Maria Hill", 0);

gridControl1.DataSource = table;
gridView1.PopulateColumns();

var column = new GridColumn();
column.FieldName = "cek22";
column.UnboundType = UnboundColumnType.Boolean;
column.UnboundExpression = "[checklist]";
column.Visible = true;

gridView1.Columns.Add(column);

gridView1.CellValueChanging += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "cek22")
        gridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "checklist", e.Value);
};
```

Here is the result:
[image: Result]

Comment: if you use unboundexpression, can user check directly from `cek22` ? because i also need to update it base on the checked. i have tried this `            dt.Columns.Add("cek",typeof(bool),"[checklist] = true");` but in the end i cant even tick or untick the checkbox

Comment: @chopperfield You can use `CellValueChanging` event. I have updated my answer.

Comment: i tried to put in event cellvaluechanged and it doesnt work. why must in `value changing` and also can you kindly explain what is  `gridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "checklist", ((bool)e.Value) ? 1 : 0);` especially the last argument `?`

Comment: @chopperfield [`CellValueChanged`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CellValueChangedtopic) event fires after closing the in-place editor. It means that user need to leave the cell to raise this event. [`CellValueChanging`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CellValueChangingtopic) occurs immediately after user ticks or unticks.

Comment: @chopperfield  [`gridView1.SetRowCellValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_SetRowCellValuetopic(uYU72g)) method sets the value of the specified cell in the `gridView1`. It uses `e.RowHandle` and `e.Value` from [`CellValueChangedEventArgs`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseCellValueChangedEventArgstopic) parameter of event.

Comment: what about `((bool)e.Value) ? 1 : 0)`?

Comment: @chopperfield `e.Value` has the type of `Object` and holds the boxed `bool` value. It needs to be converted to bool: `(bool)e.Value`. After that you need to convert this value to number. So, here is the [`?:` conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx). It is the equivalent of this if-else construction: `bool value = (bool)e.Value; int result; if (value) result = 1; else result = 0; gridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "checklist", result);`

Comment: it will take time for me to understand :). but just now randomly switch `((bool)e.Value) ? 1 : 0)` to just `e.value` it works fine. im just asking if theres any difference

Comment: @chopperfield If its working for you then its fine. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

The DevExpress Grid works with DataSource. So manipulate your DataSource and populate this to your Grid. The GridView will show this data. So if you want a check field i would recommend you to extend your DataSource with a bool Property. I don't now which DataSource you are using but if there is any bool value devexpress automatically add a checkbox column for you. If you want to link your custom column to the bool value in your DataSource you need to set the FieldName Property of the Column to your PropertyName.

If your checklist Property is 0 your bool Property return false and vice versa. This would be the easiest solution i guess. Assumed your are using a IList as DataSource.

Small example:

```
    public class MyDataSource()
    {
        public int Checklist { get; set; }

        public bool Cek22
        {
            get { return Checklist == 1; }
        }
    }

    private void ExplainADevExpressGrid()
    {
        List<MyDataSource> dataSource = new List<MyDataSource>();
        dataSource.Add(new MyDataSource());

        myGrid.DataSource = dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: i dont even know  bool value devexpress automatically add a checkbox column for you. but it doesnt work for me. is there a way like this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx but didnt add new row but set the exisisting value row

Comment: my bad, i just remember the query of column checklist was virtual, result from joining tables thats why the type was string. in devexpress bool value devexpress automatically add a checkbox column

Comment: @chopperfield think about using List<T> instead of DataTable. In my opinion it's much better to read and more comfortable. If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to come in touch with me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, add the column as part of the data source and populate it conditionally.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = GetDataTable(10);
    gridControl1.DataSource = dataTable;
}

private DataTable GetDataTable(int rows = 1)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Table1");

    table.Columns.Add("checklist", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("cek22", typeof(bool));

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["checklist"] = i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        row["cek22"] = ((int)row["checklist"]) == 0 ? false : true;

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return table;
}
```

[image]